# logging custom messages in azure postgres

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

I my stored procedures, I have inserted custom raise messages like this:

`raise warning 'proc executed for schema %',schema_name`

I want to be able to view these logs as I execute these procedures, but, I wonder how to go about doing this. I did find the [this on microsoft's page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/howto-configure-and-access-logs), and I have enabled diagnostics and sent to the log analytics workspace: [image], but, the logs after I run the query, output nothing:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where Resource == "myprivateserver"
| where Category == "PostgreSQLLogs"
```

[image]

I wonder if I'm doing it correctly or whether custom log messages as above are also logged or not.

On the left pane, I get this table containing many different things:
[image]

Comment: Did you try running AzureDiagnostics table? and checked if you got any output? Also, Can you directly check logs from PostgreSQL left pane > Logs? and then query AzureDiagnostics table?

Comment: @SiddheshDesai , I've updated my screenshot, and there are some tables that I don't understand on the left pane, could you give me a bit more designation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created stored procedure in my Azure PostgreSQL with a warning like below:-

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc(schema_name TEXT)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE WARNING 'my_proc executed for schema %', schema_name;
  -- add your procedure logic here
END;
$$;

CALL my_proc('my_schema');
```

[image]

Sent the data to Log Analytics workspace like below:-

[image]

*I checked the logs in Azure Postgresql > Left pane > logs section and ran this query but no logs on Stored procedure were present as default Diagnostic logs deals with the Azure PostgreSQL connections and error metrics in authenticating to the Azure Postgre SQL:-*

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where Category == "PostgreSQLLogs"
| where Message contains "my_proc executed for schema"
```

No output:-

[image]

I tried to inspect **AzureDiagnostics table** to fetch the Stored Procedure data but did not find any, You can also inspect each and every column from the table in left to right. Refer below:-

[image]

***As stored procedure falls under audit logs, You need to enable **Azure PostgreSQL Pgaudit extension to view the audit logs like below:-*****

[image]

Run this command to check if **Pgaudit extension** is loaded from shared library in your server like below:-

```sql
show shared_preload_libraries;
```

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION pgaudit;
```

[image]

[image]

***Now, Go to server parameters> Search for pgaudit and add WRITE permission to pgaudit.log***

[image]

***Now, I went to my Log analytics workspace where my diagnostics logs are sent and ran the below query to get the Procedure log and received the Warning message in the table output refer below:-***

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where Category == "PostgreSQLLogs"
| where Message contains "my_proc"
```

[image]

**Note- For the warning to reflect wait for some time after the pg audit extension is enabled and the warning is raised again.**

**As per your comment:-** In order to understand all the columns designation of the table, Export the query as a CSV(all columns) and inspect the Excel csv sheet like below:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDzxQ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T6Nz.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBLNU.png

**Reference:-**
[Audit logging - Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible server | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-audit)

Comment: for some reason, RAISE WARNING does print the log, but RAISE NOTICE '...' , doesn't. I've tried some log_level settings in the azure portal with no avail. Do you know what setting controls this?